# Why does RDP fail after straightforward creation of a Windows VM on Azure?

Tags: azure, credentials, remote-desktop, rdp, azure-cloud-services

I have created an Azure account (with MSDN Professional subscription), and created a G1 VM running Windows 10 Preview with Visual Studio 2015.  **However, the RDP connection reports "Your credentials did not work".**

I have attached a series of screenshots of the exact process I followed, by creating an identical second VM (with a different name, but everything else identical):

---

[image: Azure 1]

[image: Azure 2]

[image: Azure 3]

[image: Azure 4]

[image: Azure 5]

[image: Azure 6]

[image: Azure 7]

[image: Azure 8]

[image: Azure 9]

[image: Azure 10]

[image: Azure 11]

[image: Azure 12]

[image: Azure 13]

[image: Azure 14]

[image: Azure 15]

[image: Azure 16]

I have seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/19982015/368896 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/17329909/368896 - My password is 8 characters, and it contains at least one capital letter, at least one lowercase letter, at least one number, and at least one special character, with no spaces, so it should be acceptable; my username is only 10 characters with no special characters, so it should be acceptable.

**What do I need to do to connect to my Azure Windows 10 VM after I straightforwardly create it via the management console?**  Why is RDP failing?

*Note: I have disabled the firewall (Norton Antivirus) on my local machine, the one on which I run the RDP.*

Comment: Can you please try with the user `.\daniel347x`?

Comment: That worked!!  Thanks.  Can you put that as the answer?  Obviously, Azure needs to do something to make that clear for users.

Comment: ... Another odd thing I noticed.  The most recent time that I downloaded the RDP file, I notice that the 'domain' changed to the name of my local computer (the one RDP is running on) - it was not set to that domain for the previous RDP's.  Also - this was after I ran the Azure 'utility' that I found from somewhere - though after running the utility, the first time I attempted to reconnect, it failed.

Comment: Later note: I had to start from scratch with a new VM - and on this VM, I did *not* run the utility; I just downloaded the RDP, and the first time I did, it worked with the advice here.

Answer (score 1):

Like I19 suggested, it was the domain name. You can look at using Remote Desktop Connection Manager, if you are managing multiple VMs like me.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2014/01/15/using-remote-desktop-connection-manager-rdc-man-with-windows-azure-virtual-machines.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As miparnisari said, you have to put a dot and a slash before the username:

> .\username

[image]